# How to select data from child, it's parent and root of tree in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tree-like structure in database (table has column with reference to parent). How to write select query that retrieves data from child nodes, it's parent nodes and root node in one row.

For data:

```
TABLE
ID   |  NAME  |  PARENT_ID
-----+--------+-----------
1    | AAA    | NULL
2    | BBB    | 1
3    | CCC    | 2
4    | DDD    | 3
```

Result of query for should be:

```
ID   | PARENT_ID | ROOT_ID | CHILD_NAME | PARENT_NAME | ROOT_NAME
-----+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+----------
4    | 3         | 1       | DDD        | CCC         | AAA
3    | 2         | 1       | CCC        | BBB         | AAA
2    | 1         | 1       | BBB        | AAA         | AAA
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: @JamieD77 I used google before. I know what to do to get all this data vertically. But how to add columns horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other suggest: CONNECT BY

```
WITH data (id, name, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'AAA', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'BBB', 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'CCC', 2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'DDD', 3    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    ID,
    PARENT_ID,
    ROOT_ID,
    CHILD_NAME,
    PARENT_NAME,
    ROOT_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        NAME CHILD_NAME,
        PARENT_ID,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT ID ROOT_ID,
        PRIOR NAME PARENT_NAME,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT NAME ROOT_NAME
    FROM
        data
    START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID)
WHERE
    PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    ID DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing START WITH PARENT_ID IS NUL and i got ROOT_ID same as CHILD_ID using CONNECT BY ROOT.